# Passing NESTED Complex json to MVC Controllers

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

**NOTE**: It might be urging for some to mark this as an already answered question BUT it is not, I have been searching for an answer for quite a while. This is a modified version of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027245/mvc-any-version-pass-nested-complex-json-object-to-controllers", which also has not been answered.

**Question**: Is it possible to post a JSON data through jQuery ajax call to a MVC Controller where the data you are passing is a complex type with more complex types in it? Example an array of arrays.

```
var arrayOfarrays = [];
var simpleArray = [];

simpleArray[simpleArray.length] = simpleArray.length + 1;
simpleArray[simpleArray.length] = simpleArray.length + 1;
simpleArray[simpleArray.length] = simpleArray.length + 1;
simpleArray[simpleArray.length] = simpleArray.length + 1;
simpleArray[simpleArray.length] = simpleArray.length + 1;

arrayOfarrays[arrayOfarrays.length] = simpleArray;
arrayOfarrays[arrayOfarrays.length] = simpleArray;
arrayOfarrays[arrayOfarrays.length] = simpleArray;
arrayOfarrays[arrayOfarrays.length] = simpleArray;
arrayOfarrays[arrayOfarrays.length] = simpleArray;
```

The above is my data. As you see, a `simpleArray` is a mere array and the `arrayOfarrays` is an array of arrays which is in a way a nested complex type

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Save',
    data: {arrayData:simpleArray, arrayOfarrayData:arrayOfarrays},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional:true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

The above snippet is my jQuery ajax call to the controller `/Home/Save` and here below is the controller itself. Note that I have tried with and without the `traditional:true` option.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(int[] arrayData, int[][] arrayOfarrayData)
{
    return Json("received");
}
```

This is what I've observed:

- With `traditional:true` I receive the `arrayData` which is a simple array in the `/Home/Save` controller but the `arrayOfarrayData` is empty
- Without `traditional:true` I receive `arrayData` as `null` but `arrayOfarrayData` is received as an array of 5 elements but the elements are not the sub-array information you would expect but its empty

**PS:** An array of array is only an example, no NESTED complex type seem to work. Or is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to stringified your data

```
var dataToSend={
          'arrayData':simpleArray, 
          'arrayOfarrayData':arrayOfarrays
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Save',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional:true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This is correct, but as a sidenote you may need a polyfill for JSON.strigify on older browsers (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Comment: Also as a further sidenote, "traditional" is irrelevant once you're stringifying the data - it will have absolutely no impact on how it's processed, but leaving it out is probably less misleading because having it there implies it's doing something.

Comment: @user3398887 I am sorry, but using stringify alone did not fix it but thank you, I had to use stringify and contentType and then it worked, could you please modify your answer to include contentType so that I can mark it to be correct answer :)

Comment: @fyjham, thank you for the suggestions and yes, you were correct about `traditional` I even tried that out :)

Comment: Glad to know that works for you. Answer has been modified, you can mark it to be correct one.

Comment: One Query!  Why are we sending Simple arry to action if we already hav simple arry in arraryOfarrays?
& what if i want to pass Nested Json Object to Action? like `User object having Two Cars Object Inside?